# Symfony2 - notFoundExceptionError with my request

Tags: php, symfony

First , sorry for my english...
So i want to make a request to show my article by category.
But each time i just get my own error.
So my controller is :

```
 public function categorieAction($slug,$page)

{

     

    if ($page < 1) {

      throw new NotFoundHttpException('Page "'.$page.'" inexistante.');

    }

   

  $nbPerPage = 5;

   

  $listArticles = $this->getDoctrine()

    ->getManager()

    ->getRepository('OAHNewsBundle:Article')

    ->getAvecCategories($slug, $page, $nbPerPage) 

  ;

     

  $nbPages = ceil(count($listArticles)/$nbPerPage);

   

  if ($page > $nbPages) {

    throw $this->createNotFoundException("La page ".$page." n'existe pas.");

    }

   

   

    return $this->render('OAHNewsBundle:News:categorie.html.twig',array(

    'listArticles' => $listArticles,

    'nbPages'      => $nbPages,

    'page'         => $page

  ));

  }
```

My repository :

```
public function getAvecCategories ($page ,$slug, $nbPerPage )

   {

   $query = $this -> createQueryBuilder ('a')

       ->leftjoin ( 'a.categories' , 'c' )

       ->addselect('c')

       ->where('c.slug = :slug')

       ->setParameter('slug', $slug)

       ->leftjoin('a.image', 'i')

       ->addselect('i')

       ->orderBy('a.date', 'DESC')

       ->getQuery()

      ;

 

      $query

        ->setFirstResult(($page-1) * $nbPerPage)

        ->setMaxResults($nbPerPage)

    ;

         

    return new Paginator($query, true);

  

    }


    }
```

My route :

```
OAHNews_categorie:

    path:    /categorie/{slug}/{page}

    defaults: { _controller: OAHNewsBundle:News:categorie , page: 1 }

    requirements:

        page: \d*
```

And the error i get :

```
if ($page > $nbPages) {

    throw $this->createNotFoundException("La page ".$page." n'existe pas.");

    }
```

The view :

```
    {% extends "OAHNewsBundle::OAH_layout.html.twig" %}


{% block title %} {{ parent() }} - Index{% endblock %}


{% block body_news %}


    {% for article in listArticles %}

    <div class="article_des_news">


        <div class="row">


         <div class="col-sm-3">

                <a href="{{path('OAHNews_voir', {'slugarticle':article.slugarticle})}}"><img src='{{ asset(article.image.webPath) }}' alt="{{ article.image.alt}}"/></a>

         </div>


         <div class="col-sm-9">

                <a class="titre_article" href="{{path('OAHNews_voir', {'slugarticle':article.slugarticle})}}">{{article.titre}}

                </a>

                    <p><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i> par {{article.auteur}},

                     <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"> </i> {{article.date|date('d/m/y')}}

                        {% if not article.categories.empty %} 

                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-tag"> </i>

                            {% for categorie in article.categories %}

                                {{ categorie.nom }}{% if not loop.last %}, {% endif %}

                            {% endfor %}

                        {% endif %}

                    </p>

                {{ article.contenu|truncate(100, false, "...")}}    

         </div>


        </div>

    </div>

    {% endfor %}



<ul class="pagination pull-right">

  {# On utilise la fonction range(a, b) qui crée un tableau de valeurs entre a et b #}

  {% for p in range(1, nbPages) %}

    <li{% if p == page %} class="active"{% endif %}>

      <a href="{{ path('OAHNews_accueil', {'page': p}) }}">{{ p }}</a>

    </li>

  {% endfor %}

</ul>


{% endblock %}
```

and the link i use :

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">

  {% for categorie in listCategories %}

    <li class='menu'>

      <a class="titre_article normalLink" href="{{ path('OAHNews_categorie', {'slug': categorie.slug}) }}">

        {{ categorie.nom }}

      </a>

    </li>

  {% endfor %}

</ul>
```

So what's wrong with my request? 
Thank you !

Comment: Can you show how you call your page ?

Comment: Ty, but i wanted to see the link you're using to access your page. :)

Comment: I edited again. Ty !

Comment: So any idea  please ?

Comment: Yeah i have an idea but i am on my phone and it is definitely not easy to answer. I post my as soon as I am on a Pc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I got it ! You're using a Paginator object. This object doesn't give you the results at all. If you want to get the number of `articles`, you have to do :

```
$listArticles->count()
```

According with [the doc of the class](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.4/class-Doctrine.ORM.Tools.Pagination.Paginator.html)

But care, cause you've a little problem of logic on your 'existing page check' : Your Repository can only return to you a maximum of 5 results, so if you try to access the second page, you'll have something like that :

```
$nbPages = ceil($listArticles->count()/$nbPerPage); // [0 - 5] / 5 = 0 or 1

  if ($page > $nbPages) { // if (2 > 0 or 1)
    throw $this->createNotFoundException("La page ".$page." n'existe pas.");
  }
```

If you want to check if you're accessing an existing page, you just can do :

```
if ($listArticles->count() > 0) {
    throw $this->createNotFoundException("La page ".$page." n'existe pas.");
}
```

And in your return you must send the array of results to your template by doing :

```
 return $this->render('OAHNewsBundle:News:categorie.html.twig',array(

    'listArticles' => $listArticles->getIterator(),

    'nbPages'      => $nbPages,

    'page'         => $page

 ));
```

Problem 2 : You have the error of the offset equal -5 because of this line of your repo :

```
->setFirstResult(($page-1) * $nbPerPage) // $page = 0 so (0-1) * 5 = -5
```

And this is because you defined you `getAvecCategories` like that :

```
getAvecCategories ($page ,$slug, $nbPerPage ) // page, slug, nbPerPage
```

And you're calling it by inversing arguments :

```
 ->getAvecCategories($slug, $page, $nbPerPage) // slug, page, nbPerPage
```

So php try to cast a slug in int and return 0.

Comment: Your method send me the following error : LIMIT argument offset=-5 is not valid. And i don't understand why my argument is negative here...

Comment: Yeah that proves that it works better. I edited my answer with the second problem

Answer (score 0):

The route should be

```
OAHNews_categorie:
    path:    /categorie/{slug}/{page}
    defaults: { _controller: OAHNewsBundle:News:categorie , page: 1 }
    requirements:
        page: \d+ <-- change \d* by \d+
```

Try [to cast](https://secure.php.net/manual/fr/function.intval.php) the variable before check :

```
  if (intval($page) > $nbPages) {
    throw $this->createNotFoundException("La page ".$page." n'existe pas.");
  }
```

Else, `dump($page)` and `dump($nbPages)` to know which value you get and understand why the conparison failed.

Comment: I have still the same error with \d+ and apparently the int() doesn't work on my repository

Comment: You have to clear the cache if you are not in debug mode. Sorry it was `intval()` function. I have updated the answer.

Comment: Always the same error... You think there's no problem with my request?

Comment: Just a little question : How many products do you have in your database ?

Comment: @Flushdrew, depends, what do you have if you echoed your variable $page? `dump($page);` or `var_dump($page);` then `exit;` to display only this data?

Comment: @julienbourdic , i have enought article on my db. Just one by catégorie will works no?